# AWS replication failure - could not access file "pglogical"

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-replication, aws-dms, postgresql-13

After 2 months running without problems, my AWS DMS task failed with the following error:

```
Last failure message
Last Error Stream Component Fatal error. Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2880] [1020101] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component; Stream component terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2888] [1020101] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL
```

In my CloudWatch logs I found: `NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: could not access file "pglogical": No such file or directory; Error while executing the query`  and later `ERROR: relation "pglogical.replication_set" does not exist; No query has been executed with that handle`.

I noticed I didn't enable pglogical in my `postgresql.conf` so I updated `shared_preload_libraries`:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pglogical'
```

Postgres doesn't start with that setting, just fails.
At the same time, I think that there might be another reason why the DMS task fails every time I'm trying to start it, as previously I didn't have that problem.

What else can I try to resolve this issue?

Here are some of the settings in my postgres.conf

```
wal_level = logical
max_wal_senders = 10            # max number of walsender processes
wal_sender_timeout = 0          # in milliseconds; 0 disables
max_replication_slots = 10      # max number of replication slots
```

Source: PostgreSQL 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1.pgdg18.04+1)
Target: Aurora PostgreSQL 13.7
DMS task type: Full load, ongoing replication

Answer (score 0):

After adding `pglogical` to `shared_preload_libraries`, you need to restart your instance. Then, make sure you enable the extension by running:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pglogical;
```

Then check this is running:

```sql
select * FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension;
```

Last thing is: make sure you set the source endpoint extra parameter `PluginName=pglogical`. This is supposed to be used by default when it's installed though.

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.v10)

Answer (score 0):

To add pglogical you have to install it first on your system.

On Ubuntu just use apt

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-<YOUR POSTGRES VERSION>-pglogical
```

After that, you could restart postgres with the `shared_preload_libraries = 'pglogical'` setting